# Unwanted Behaviour of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, xcode6, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am trying to display some text in `UICollection` view. But i am getting the error that

> Property cell label not fount on object of type
>   UICOllectionViewCell

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

 @interface ViewController :     UIViewController<UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate>


  @end
```

.m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
 }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return 10;
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
NSString *cellIdentifier  =@"cell";
UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell.cellLabel.text = @"Sample Text";
return cell;
}
@end
```

I have already set the delgate methods of `UICollectionView`.
[Here is the Screenshot of Error](http://screencast.com/t/rPmaWMxe)

Comment: have you added a label to your `collectionview` cell?

Comment: no i haven't added anything to collectionview cell. I only created tableviewcell

Comment: then how can you assume this `cell.cellLabel.text = @"Sample Text";`

Comment: after creating label i get this err http://screencast.com/t/eby6bEdr9

Comment: how you are creating label?

Comment: first i have selected the layout type of UICollectionview as Custom then i drag and doped la label on cell.

Comment: c this http://screencast.com/t/wEEUxUpHl

Comment: have you make a property outlet of that label?

Comment: I also tried what you told but it doesn't work. Still stucked

Comment: have you checked my ans below have you tried both of the solutions? there is also a link of a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your cellLabel outlet set in interface builder?

If NO then make one.

You should have something like this in your cell's .h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *cellLabel;
```

then later you really just need to do this:

```
cell.cellLabel.text = @"";
```

You can also make a label like this,

```
UILabel *cellLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, cell.bounds.size.width, 40)]; //custom size

[cell.contentView addSubview:cellLabel];
```

and use it like

```
cell.cellLabel.text = @"Sample Text";
```

There are tutorial on `UICollectionView` you can have a look on [this link.](http://nscookbook.com/2013/02/ios-programming-recipe-14-implementing-a-uicollectionviewcontroller/)

Comment: Tags are hard to maintain, don't have a type and the compiler can't help you if you make some change. Please try to avoid them.

Comment: http://screencast.com/t/FOaJLBRe    still getting err after doing what you say @saadChaudhry

Comment: i am following this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012334-CH7-SW1    and the link you gave is about UICollectionViewController and i am looking for only UICollectionView

Comment: Documentation says : "Listing 2-2  Configuring a custom cell", 

please check the tutorial link and  see how it makes a custom cell, then register it and use it.

Comment: @SaadChaudhry i doen't understand what is MyCustomCell in Listing2-2

Comment: MyCustomCell is your custom CollectionViewCell class.

Answer (score 0):

First note that even if you have a custom cell you are dequeing your collection view cell to a custom one :

```
UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

In compile time the compiler doesn't know you are trying to use your custom cell, therefore that property doesn't exist.

Be sure that you:

- Created a custom UICollectionViewCell that has your cellLabel property
- That you registered your cell via code OR you used your cell identifier in the Interface Builder
- That you imported your cell and you are using it in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: If your custom collectionview cell is called: "URCustomCollectionViewCell" then you have to import it and do `URCustomCollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];`. Then you can use your label.

Comment: i got that what are you saying but how i know that is my cell called as i haven't changed any name or given any name to collectioncell

Comment: You can follow this simple tutorial http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/creating-custom-collection-view-cells-in-ios7 . Note that you need something like "MyCell" in that tutorial but with a label instead of an image.